# My Foreach loop needs optimization

Tags: c#, if-statement, foreach, unity-game-engine

I'm working in Unity, writing some C# for a terrain hide/reveal code.
**The code works**, but is there a way to rewrite this so that I wont have to keep writing this loooong code out every time I encounter one of these pretty simple situations?

Here are the variables relevant to this part:

```
// ...

private int terLevel = 0;
private GameObject[] t0;
private GameObject[] t1;
private GameObject[] t2;
private GameObject[] t3;
private GameObject[] t4;
private GameObject[] t5;
```

Here is the relevant part of my start function:

```
void Start ()
    {
        // ...

        t0 = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("T0");
        t1 = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("T1");
        t2 = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("T2");
        t3 = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("T3");
        t4 = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("T4");
        t5 = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("T5");
    }
```

And here are is the **main part** I want to fix in my update function:

```
void Update ()
    {
        // ...

        if(terLevel <= 0)
    {
        foreach(GameObject i in t1)
            i.renderer.enabled = false;
        foreach(GameObject i in t2)
            i.renderer.enabled = false;
        foreach(GameObject i in t3)
            i.renderer.enabled = false;
        foreach(GameObject i in t4)
            i.renderer.enabled = false;
        foreach(GameObject i in t5)
            i.renderer.enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
    if(terLevel == 1)
    {
        foreach(GameObject i in t1)
            i.renderer.enabled = true;
        foreach(GameObject i in t2)
            i.renderer.enabled = false;
        foreach(GameObject i in t3)
            i.renderer.enabled = false;
        foreach(GameObject i in t4)
            i.renderer.enabled = false;
        foreach(GameObject i in t5)
            i.renderer.enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
    if(terLevel == 2)
    {
        foreach(GameObject i in t1)
            i.renderer.enabled = true;
        foreach(GameObject i in t2)
            i.renderer.enabled = true;
        foreach(GameObject i in t3)
            i.renderer.enabled = false;
        foreach(GameObject i in t4)
            i.renderer.enabled = false;
        foreach(GameObject i in t5)
            i.renderer.enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
    if(terLevel == 3)
    {
        foreach(GameObject i in t1)
            i.renderer.enabled = true;
        foreach(GameObject i in t2)
            i.renderer.enabled = true;
        foreach(GameObject i in t3)
            i.renderer.enabled = true;
        foreach(GameObject i in t4)
            i.renderer.enabled = false;
        foreach(GameObject i in t5)
            i.renderer.enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
    if(terLevel == 4)
    {
        foreach(GameObject i in t1)
            i.renderer.enabled = true;
        foreach(GameObject i in t2)
            i.renderer.enabled = true;
        foreach(GameObject i in t3)
            i.renderer.enabled = true;
        foreach(GameObject i in t4)
            i.renderer.enabled = true;
        foreach(GameObject i in t5)
            i.renderer.enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
    if(terLevel >= 5)
    {
        foreach(GameObject i in t1)
            i.renderer.enabled = true;
        foreach(GameObject i in t2)
            i.renderer.enabled = true;
        foreach(GameObject i in t3)
            i.renderer.enabled = true;
        foreach(GameObject i in t4)
            i.renderer.enabled = true;
        foreach(GameObject i in t5)
            i.renderer.enabled = true;
    }}}}}}
}
```

Terrifying isn't it.  Imagine if I had more than 5 terrain layers, I would die before I finished the code.  There must be a

Comment: Would be better in [CodeReview.SE]?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If you're curious on what this code does, it's basically a way to hide all the terrain layers above what you are working on.
I don't have the buttons shown here, but the premise here is:
You press the upTerrain button, it reveals one layer from the bottom up.
If you press the downTerrain button, it hides the highest visible layer.

Comment: Please use `unity3d` tag for questions related to Unity game engine. It's generally a good idea to read the tags descriptions before applying them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by putting all of your game objects into a single array:

```
private GameObject[][] ts = new GameObject[6][];
```

From there the rest becomes pretty simple. First populate:

```
void Start ()
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++)
    {
        ts[i] = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(string.Format("T{0}", i));
    }
}
```

And updating:

```
void Update ()
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++)
    {
        foreach(GameObject t in ts)
            t.renderer.enabled = i > terLevel;
    }
}
```

Comment: oh my goodness, that's genious!  thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

quick shot:

```
    foreach(GameObject i in t1)
        i.renderer.enabled = terLevel > 0;
    foreach(GameObject i in t2)
        i.renderer.enabled = terLevel > 1;
    foreach(GameObject i in t3)
        i.renderer.enabled = terLevel > 2;
    foreach(GameObject i in t4)
        i.renderer.enabled = terLevel > 3;
    foreach(GameObject i in t5)
        i.renderer.enabled = terLevel > 4;
```

Comment: sorry, no if around ... answer corrected